# Visual Studio - Breakpoints not being hit with Array.map

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, f#, visual-studio-2022

In the code below ( which is part of a function with = task{ )

Breakpoint 3 is being hit - and breakpoint 1 and 2 are not. the code is working ( i.e. the code is running in the Array.map and produces 29 rows but I can no longer debug that part of the code ). They were breakking and then they just stopped all of a sudden.  Tried resetting settings, rebooting machine etc.  Any ideas?  All the builds are debug / Any CPU

```
                let rows = 
                    data.Rows
                    |> Seq.toArray
                    |> Array.map(fun row -> 
                        let transactionDateString = row[0] + " " + row[1] //Breakpoint 1
                        let ttt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(DateTime.Parse(transactionDateString, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-AU")),TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. Australia Standard Time"),TimeZoneInfo.Local)
                        let transactionDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(transactionDateString, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddHours(2)
                        let ttt2 = ttt.ToLocalTime()
                        let transactionNumber = row.Columns[2].ToString() // [ "TRXN Reference-Eway"]
                        let t2 = int transactionNumber  // Breakpoint 2

                        let transactionType = row[3].ToString()
                        let transactionCurrency = currency

                        let csvData: EwayCSVData = {
                            transactionDateTime = transactionDateTime
                            transactionNumber = transactionNumber
                            transactionType = transactionType
                            currency = transactionCurrency
                        }
                        csvData)

                do! EwayTransactions.saveTransactions(rows,sTransCollection, httpClient) // Breakpoint 3
```